# Application Logger

Tags: c#, database, logging

Folks.. Our customer is asking for a new requirement which allow our application to log every important event generated by the user, for example lets say user A changes the phoneNumber property  from (305)-5555-555 to (906)-5555-555, we have to log this event occurence in a readable format. something like

```
  updated phoneNumber from (305)-5555-555 to (906)-5555-555, responsible: User A.
```

my question, does exists a well-known approach to do that, may be a technique or tool or anything ?, or we have  to implement every log by hand by adding a whole logic to my current source code ??

we are using ASP.Net with C# !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools you can use. NLog and Log4Net being two examples. There is no magic bullet that is going to log these events for you without coding them.

If you are using Entity Models you might be able to inject the logging using AOP. Have a look at [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). This is a very useful tool that can save you a lot of tedious coding.

Comment: The authors of PostSharp vote against using it in an ASP.NET scenario. In addition there is an additinal project trying to remove these limitations: http://postsharp4aspnet.codeplex.com/ (I haven't used it).

Answer (score 2):

Application event logging is a must. But most available logging modules around are quite bloated or heavy structured. Why not create your own simple file logger and gain full control over this part of your application? Find a full sample implementation [HERE](http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/32).

Comment: Great tip AND code!!!!  Other answers are for Objective-C and I need to log issues happening in C++.  Thank you.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I have used Nlog in the past and it worked well

Answer (score 0):

Use **log4Net** we have used it many times and it is the best logging tool out there for free and open source!

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

log4net is a tool to help the programmer output log statements to a variety of output targets. In case of problems with an application, it is helpful to enable logging so that the problem can be located. With log4net it is possible to enable logging at runtime without modifying the application binary. The log4net package is designed so that log statements can remain in shipped code without incurring a high performance cost.
log4net is designed with two distinct goals in mind: speed and flexibility

Use the sample code from website and start and enjoy!